# Div inside div, prevent overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside another div and when I set margin and padding to the inner div it overlaps with parent.

How can I prevent the inner div overlapping?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kcaavzt/1/) of the below:

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.inner {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**: Try position:relative for the parent div and position:absolute for the inner div and add 5px each to the top,left,bottom and right, to push it from all sides:

```
.outer {
  border:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.inner {
  padding:5px;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  right:5px;
  position:absolute;
  border:1px;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kcaavzt/2/

**Method 2** Add display:table to the parent div and add 5px padding to it than adding margin to the inner div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kcaavzt/4/

Answer (score 2):

1. remove `margin:5px;` for `.inner`
2. add `padding: 5px`  parent  `.outer`
3. add `box-sizing` for `.inner` - 100% + padding 5px > 100%

```css
.outer {
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;   
    padding: 5px;
}
.inner {
    padding:5px;    
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;  
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the winner -- [More information on `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for anyone interested.

Comment: When building something new, box-size all div's by default:
div {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
Then margin-, overflow-, padding problems belong to the past.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `div` overlaps because you introduced a 5px offset via `margin`, yet set its height and width to `100%`, which is the parent's height, 250px.

[image]

You can try setting the height and width to `100% - 2 * margin` using CSS3:

```
.inner {
    height:calc(100% - 2 * 5px);
}
```

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqgL35L9/)